# Safe Temperature for GPU and CPU while gaming in laptop

Tags: cpu, gpu, temperature

I currently have the ASUS ROG GL553VE. and while gaming, i usually open up ROG gaming center and Real temp. what i noticed is that my GPU usually gets 84C and my CPU's get about 75-89C. is that kinda normal? i am playing with a cooling pad too. i ask other people about this problem, and some said that its not normal since its too hot, and some said that it is normal since gaming laptop really does get hot when playing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming that your computer has Intel i7-7700HQ processor and it is a laptop it is quite ok.

Laptops generally run hotter due to their size and cooling configurations.

To prevent any problems you should provide a good cooling and keep an eye on your PC.

Note: [Open Hardware Monitor](http://openhardwaremonitor.org) - good open source program to monitor your hardware stats.

Comment: T_Junction for this CPU is 100°C. It is in no way overheating.

Comment: Well, maybe but I would still keep an eye on that PC.

Comment: @COOL_IRON - If the system isn't overheating to the point where the system is shutting itself down the system is fine.